# how i can get data from binance on Vscode

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to get data from binance client using python on VSCode .

```
from binance import Client
import config

key = config.API_KEY
secret = config.API_SECRET

client = Client(key, secret)

info = client.get_symbol_info("BTCUSDT")
```

I tryed the same code on google collab and it worked. but I always have the error

`'Client' object has no attribute`

when I run the code using VSCode .

Comment: which attribute? from the error message

Comment: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_symbol_info'

Comment: I even tryed other attribute like :
 client.get_all_tickers()
 client.get_products()
and it's allways the same error .

Comment: look into the code of `Client` to see what it supports

Comment: ok thank you ill check it ! acctually i didnt understand why it work google colab and not vscode, i import all librarys and it same python version

Comment: it does not depend on the python version but the version of the libraries

Comment: but i used the same libraries version.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall and reinstall python-binance

Comment: Please add more clarification.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).